# Was Kobato's origin ever mentioned?

Tags: kobato

Kobato has a mission to fill a mysterious bottle with people's healed hearts. However, it wasn't explained in the anime as to why she has this mission or her origin. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobato.#Characters) doesn't seem to know anything about it as well so I'm curious if CLAMP ever mentioned her story before she came collecting jar of hearts and why she had that wish to go to a certain place. Or was her story featured in any of the CLAMP's multiverse or in the manga?

Comment: Are you sure the last paragraph of Kobato's description on the page you linked doesn't answer your questions?

Comment: Yeah it did, my bad. I guess I was lazy when I read the page. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops.. Sorry my bad. I was too lazy to read the whole [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobato.#Characters) when it already contained the answer.. :P

> At the conclusion of the anime, it is revealed that Kobato died in the
>   distant past. She exists in a liminal state where she neither dead nor
>   alive. In the end, when she finally fulfills her task to fill the
>   flask, she is reborn without any memories of her past life until she
>   meets Fujimoto again few years later. In the manga, it is revealed
>   that Kobato had died due to the war caused by Ioryogi and the gods.
>   The angel that Ioryogi had fallen in love with felt pity for the girl
>   who died before her time was up and transferred her soul into Kobato,
>   being able to since they both have the same soul but belong to
>   different worlds. The time limit Kobato has is the time before the
>   angel disappears.

Comment: In the manga, the background of being neither alive nor dead is the same, yet the conclusion is rather different. In the anime, she loses her memory upon being reborn and regains them for no apparent reason when encountering Fujimoto. In the manga, she retains her memories after being reborn and goes back to the kindergarten where, by chance, she encounters Fujimoto (since he doesn't work there anymore). Ginseis wish to God is then fulfilled and restores the memories of Fujimoto (Good job, grumpy Ginsei).